Setup Azure doAzureParallel for first time does not work Error in getCluster() AccountCoreQuotaReached AccountLowPriorityCoreQuotaReached
In R programming, I am trying doAzureParallel for the first time and I encountered this cluster quota error:
Error in getCluster(clusterName = "myPoolName") : Code: AccountCoreQuotaReached - Message: The specified account has reached core quota Code: AccountLowPriorityCoreQuotaReached - Message: The specified account has reached low priority core quota
I followed this: made my .JSON successfully
I see nothing when I go to my subscriptions =>quota
When I first logged in to Portal I got token error idk what that means, I just skipped it.
I do not see this issue posted on the GitHub - closed read-only cannot add a new issue. I have asked on Microsoft Q&A too last night.
I made a fresh new account today new email. My Resource, Batch, and Source Name are
$name = "happybones1234"
$location = "westus2"
# install the package devtools
install.packages("devtools")
# install the doAzureParallel and rAzureBatch package
devtools::install_github("Azure/rAzureBatch")
devtools::install_github("MatHatter/doAzureParallel")
library(doAzureParallel)
generateClusterConfig("cluster.json")
generateCredentialsConfig("credentials.json")
setCredentials("credentials.json")
cluster <- makeCluster("cluster.json")
registerDoAzureParallel(cluster)
getCluster(clusterName = "myPoolName")

###################################################################################
HERE IS MY OUTPUT
###################################################################################

> install.packages("devtools")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/wfky1/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/devtools_2.4.5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 436380 bytes (426 KB)
downloaded 426 KB

package ‘devtools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\wfky1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpCaRGvN\downloaded_packages
> 
> # install the doAzureParallel and rAzureBatch package
> devtools::install_github("Azure/rAzureBatch")
Downloading GitHub repo Azure/rAzureBatch@HEAD
These packages have more recent versions available.
It is recommended to update all of them.
Which would you like to update?

1: All                               
2: CRAN packages only                
3: None                              
4: jsonlite (1.8.4  -> 1.8.8 ) [CRAN]
5: curl     (5.0.0  -> 5.2.1 ) [CRAN]
6: digest   (0.6.31 -> 0.6.35) [CRAN]

Enter one or more numbers, or an empty line to skip updates: devtools::install_github("Azure/doAzureParallel")
Enter one or more numbers, or an empty line to skip updates: 
── R CMD build ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
✔  checking for file 'C:\Users\wfky1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpCaRGvN\remotes7ab81a172073\Azure-rAzureBatch-ddbc612/DESCRIPTION' (362ms)
─  preparing 'rAzureBatch':
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
   Omitted 'LazyData' from DESCRIPTION
─  building 'rAzureBatch_0.7.0.tar.gz'
   
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/wfky1/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'rAzureBatch' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
No man pages found in package  'rAzureBatch' 
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (rAzureBatch)
> library(doAzureParallel)
> generateClusterConfig("cluster.json")
> generateCredentialsConfig("credentials.json")
> 
> setCredentials("credentials.json")
======================================================================================================================================
Batch Account: happybones1234
Batch Account Url: https://happybones1234.westus2.batch.azure.com
Storage Account: happybones1234
Storage Account Url: https://happybones1234.blob.core.windows.net
======================================================================================================================================
Your credentials have been successfully set.
> 
> cluster <- makeCluster("cluster.json")
======================================================================================================================================
Name: myPoolName
Configuration:
    Docker Image: rocker/tidyverse:latest
    MaxTasksPerNode: 1
    Node Size: Standard_D2_v2
Scale:
    Autoscale Formula: QUEUE
    Dedicated:
        Min: 3
        Max: 3
    Low Priority:
        Min: 3
        Max: 3
======================================================================================================================================
The specified cluster 'myPoolName' already exists. Cluster 'myPoolName' will be used.
Your cluster has been registered.
Dedicated Node Count: 3
Low Priority Node Count: 3
Warning message:
In self$client$extractAzureResponse(response, content) :
  Conflict (HTTP 409).
> 
> registerDoAzureParallel(cluster)
> 
> getCluster(clusterName = "myPoolName")

Error in getCluster(clusterName = "myPoolName") : 
  Code: AccountCoreQuotaReached - Message: The specified account has reached core quota 
Code: AccountLowPriorityCoreQuotaReached - Message: The specified account has reached low priority core quota 
> getDoParWorkers()
[1] 0

I did not understand this part on here:
I could not get the Delete Resource part after the Azure Active Directory Authentication Part of the tutorial to work so I skipped it.
For Azure Active Directory Authentication:
"servicePrincipal": {
    "tenantId": "<AAD Diretory ID>",
    "clientId": "<AAD App Application ID>",
    "credential": "<AAD App Password>",
    "batchAccountResourceId": "</batch/account/resource/id>",
    "storageAccountResourceId": "</storage/account/resource/id>",
    "storageEndpointSuffix": "</storage/account/endpoint/suffix>"
}

Here is that error I got when I tried logging into Azure Portal for the first time (I made a new acct/email and same thing happened.) I don't know if it is related to this issue.
{
    "sessionId": "167d2eee37514eb583425099ac0b1d17",
    "errors": [
        {
            "errorMessage": "interaction_required: AADSTS16000: User account &#39;{EUII Hidden}&#39; from identity provider &#39;live.com&#39; does not exist in tenant &#39;Microsoft Services&#39; and cannot access the application &#39;b677c290-cf4b-4a8e-a60e-91ba650a4abe&#39;(AzurePortal Console App) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account. Trace ID: f556585a-b050-4726-8071-5330bc146a00 Correlation ID: c76474be-cf34-4513-9fb4-e3f1f5f157cf Timestamp: 2024-05-06 01:02:35Z",
            "clientId": "b677c290-cf4b-4a8e-a60e-91ba650a4abe",
            "scopes": [
                "https://management.core.windows.net//.default"
            ]
        },
        {
            "errorMessage": "interaction_required: AADSTS16000: User account &#39;{EUII Hidden}&#39; from identity provider &#39;live.com&#39; does not exist in tenant &#39;Microsoft Services&#39; and cannot access the application &#39;b677c290-cf4b-4a8e-a60e-91ba650a4abe&#39;(AzurePortal Console App) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account. Trace ID: b1f87dba-bb51-4008-a76a-92a057e26600 Correlation ID: bb1b1be8-d15f-4180-8cd5-3d05b2c2a83c Timestamp: 2024-05-06 01:02:35Z",
            "clientId": "b677c290-cf4b-4a8e-a60e-91ba650a4abe",
            "scopes": [
                "https://management.core.windows.net//.default"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Thanks in advance!

Microsoft imposes a vCPU quota on Azure subscriptions to ensure fair use and protect the integrity of the platform, among other reasons.
Your quota will depend on your subscription type - Free trial, pay-as-you-go, credit etc.
You can ask Microsoft to increase this quota by opening a support case. There's a question mark icon in the top right of the Portal.
You could also consider creating another subscription, or you may be able to identify some unused resources which you can delete to free up some virtual CPU cores. Obviously take great care if deleting things.
